# Hi, I need to generate apk of my PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

I need to generate apk of PowerApps. I tried several ways and able to generate apk but after installing gives error like "The redirect URI 'msauth://com.iosPowerAppNameSPList/OwfLlHwtKHJAmZo36omno%2Fg1F7Y%3D' specified in the request does not match the redirect URI's configured for the application".

Steps I followed:

1. Created App in Azure Portal.
2. Generated signature hash using Android Studio.
3. Registered Platform as "Android" in Azure Apps. Added Signature Hash and Copied generated RedirectURI.
4. Generated apk using wrap wizard of PowerApps.
5. Manual sign-in apk.